# Jquery .animate for nested div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a `nav` that scrolls to its corresponding explanation section. The thing is, the explanation sections are so long that I decided to set them in a `div` with a fixed `height` and `overflow-y:scroll`.

Here's my JS:

```
$('.target').click(function() {
       var id = $(this).data('link');
       navigateToElement(id);
    });



    function navigateToElement(id) {
        $('.nest').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top
        }, 500);
    }
```

Now when I click the `nav`, the `fixed-height div` animates quite strangely. Case in point, check out the fiddle and click the yellow `nav div`, then click the blue `nav div`. It just fidgets around.

Here's the fiddle: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/v2h14o8m/1/)

Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I remember having to solve a similar issue. Maybe you can have a look at my github repo and feel free to grab code snippets. I apologize about the code quality, this was one of my earlier projects.

[https://github.com/quantumlicht/cv-central][1]

The code that will most likely be of interest is the scroll spy function and utils setSkrollr in the scripts/js folder. Please reach out if you need more help.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question.